# anonymous functions as parameters

Tags: javascript

```
function cbTest(name,function(){
    console.log("Hello ",name);
})


cbTest("john");
```

I am getting the following error.

> ```
> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {  
>      function cbTest(name,function(){
>                           ^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token `function`
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
>     at startup (node.js:117:18)
>     at node.js:951:3

What's wrong with this code?

Update:
I tried to make anonymous function work as parameter, but anyhow, the below should be the way.

```
function getName(name){
    return name;
}

function cbTest(name,cb){
    console.log("hello ",cb(name));
}

cbTest("John",getName);
```

Comment: what should this code do in your opinion? you're declaring a function and instead of parameter list you enter some function

Comment: Functions cannot be *parameters*, but they can be *arguments*.

Answer (score 4):

When you're declaring a function, the parameter list can only consist of names for the parameters (well, plus the spread operator `...` in ES2015). You're trying to declare a function with an instantiated function in the parameter list, which just doesn't make sense.

Anonymous functions make sense in the parameter list when you're **calling** the function, but not when you're **declaring** it.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make any sense

It can be either:

```
function cbTest(name) {
    console.log("Hello ",name);
}

cbTest("john");
```

or

```
function cbTest(name, func) {
    func(name);
}


cbTest("john", function(name){
    console.log("Hello ",name);
});
```

You cannot pass anything in function declaration

Comment: Your second example should be `func('foo')` instead of `func(name)`.

Comment: 2nd example works ! prints "Hello John". 
@gcampbell works too. prints "Hello foo". 
Thanks!